# finding the d3.extent of an array with dates to create xScale in D3

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to create a focus brush, similar to this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367, using a json file. 
I am   having a problem to correctly read the date and create the xScale for the chart.

Say these are some of the dates in my Json file, extracted into an array.

```
//some dates
        dates = ["Fri Jul 27 22:32:59 2012","Fri Jul 27 22:33:59 2012","Fri Jul 27 22:34:59 2012","Fri Jul 27 22:35:59 2012","Fri Jul 27 22:36:59 2012"];

        //declare new date variable
        var dates2 =[];


        var format = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
        dates.forEach(function(d){
             dates2.push(format.parse(d));
        });
        console.log(d3.extent(dates_extents));

                    dates_extents = d3.extent(dates2);

        x.domain(d3.extent(dates_extents);
        x2.domain(x.domain);
```

Althought the dates_extents is printed in the console, I get this error:

```
TypeError: n.map is not a function [Break On This Error] ...t,n)},n.copy=function(){return ae(t)},n}function oe(t){return t.innerRadius}func... d3.v3.min.js (line 1)
```

Any ideas what might be the source of the problem and how I can solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't work because you're referencing a variable before defining it. Could you also please post where exactly this error occurs?

Comment: Thanks Lars, it seems i've forgotten to add "()" after the x.domain.